# What are the formatting pattern semantics in Java Util Logging?

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I am trying to make sense of the formatting patterns used in Java Util Logging.
Just by experiment I see the following:

```
%1$ts     epoch time: 1657069724
%1$tc     Standard date/time format: Tue Jul 05 20:59:21 EDT 2022
%1$tY     year - 2022
%1$tb     3 char month - Jul
%1$th     3 char month - Jul
%1$tm     2 digit month - 07
%1$td     2 digit day of month - 05
%1$tH:    hours (0-23) 21:
%1$tM:    minutes: 03:
%1$tS.    Seconds: 55.
%1$tL     Milleseconds 294
%2$s      logger name and method
%3$s      logger name
%4$-7s    log level of this message - WARNING
```

(the -7 before the s means left justify in a 7 character field. Remove the "-" to right justify)

Are these documented anywhere? I do not see anything in the SimpleFormat API or in Java Util Logging docs

Comment: This is documented by [`SimpleFormatter#format(LogRecord)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format(java.util.logging.LogRecord)), which formats the log record "as if by calling [`String.format(format, date, source, logger, level, message, thrown)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))", where the format pattern is documented by [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: (assuming you're using a `SimpleFormatter`)

Comment: Yes we are using SimpleFormatter, but I don't see any description of the syntax %1$ts. I understand that %1 is the field reference, but what about the $t, and what are the formatting letters following that, m,d,H,S,L etc?

Comment: As shown in the documentation of `java.util.Formatter` (linked previously), the `t` is "_Prefix for date and time conversion characters_". And then if you go to the "Date/Time Conversions" section, you'll see what letters such as `m`, `d`, etc. mean. For instance, `%1$ts` is formatting the first argument as a date/time, specifically into "_Seconds since the beginning of the epoch starting at 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC_".

Answer (score 3):

[`java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter::format`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format(java.util.logging.LogRecord)) explains this:

> The formatting can be customized by specifying the format string in the java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format property. The given LogRecord will be formatted as if by calling:
>
> ```
> String.format(format, date, source, logger, level, message, thrown);
> ```
>
> where the arguments are:
>
> 1. format - the java.util.Formatter format string specified in the java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format property or the default format.
> 2. date - a ZonedDateTime object representing event time of the log record in the ZoneId.systemDefault() system time zone.
> 3. source - a string representing the caller, if available; otherwise, the logger's name.
> 4. logger - the logger's name.
> 5. level - the log level.
> 6. message - the formatted log message returned from the Formatter.formatMessage(LogRecord) method. It uses java.text formatting and does not use the java.util.Formatter format argument.
> 7. thrown - a string representing the throwable associated with the log record and its backtrace beginning with a newline character, if any; otherwise, an empty string.

Note that the `%[argument_index$]` is off by one from the javadocs in SimpleFormatter as `format` is listed as the argument number one.  E.G. `date` is listed as `2` but is really `%1$`.

[String::format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) has a "see" reference to [`java.util.Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html) (not to be confused with `java.util.logging.Formatter`).

The class level documentation of `java.util.Formatter' includes information on 'Date/Time Conversions' and 'Flags'.

If you use [parameterized logging](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/Logger.html#log(java.util.logging.Level,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) you can also do some formatting with [java.text.MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/MessageFormat.html) on the parameters of a LogRecord.  This can be used to change the behavior of the 'message' parameter passed to `String::format`.

Comment: I don't think it's off by one in the documentation. When it says "_where the arguments are_", it's talking about (and listing) the arguments to the `String.format` **method** itself, not the arguments to be formatted. And in that context, `date` is definitely the second (`2`) argument.

Comment: @Slaw Wouldn't it be a given that Java method parameters are zero based indexes?  Java var-args are based on arrays.  Java arrays are zero based.  Therefore, method parameters too would be zero based meaning the list would start at zero.  The documentation in its current form has little utility for constructing and deconstructing SimpleFormatter patterns.  As a consumer of SimpleFormatter it is more useful to know date is `%1$` vs. the second parameter to an implementation detail.  At any rate, I filed a JDK bug so I'll update and or remove the opinion part of my answer as that progresses.

Comment: (1/2) I understand where you're coming from, but not sure I agree. First, it's not an implementation detail—it's documented. No matter what this method does, the end result must be equivalent to having called `String.format(format, date, source, logger, level, message, thrown);`. But that doesn't tell you what the arguments actually are. That's what the list is for. Could the HTML list be zero-based? Perhaps, but I don't think it would make it more readable. Second, this documentation has no need to document `%[argument_index$]`, because that's documented by `String.format` / `Formatter`, and

Comment: (2/2) we know the order of the arguments to `String.format` due to the documentation. But it will be interesting to see what the bug report yields.

Comment: @Slaw _Could the HTML list be zero-based?_ Yes. See: [com.sun.mail.util.logging.CompactFormatter](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/util/logging/CompactFormatter.html#format-java.util.logging.LogRecord-)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. That was a rhetorical question.

Comment: @Slaw _That's what the list is for._ Yep and that list is wrong.  Let's use that list to build a pattern that prints the `message` and `throwable`.  `%6$%7$%n` right?  Nope.  Per SimpleFormatter examples in javadoc later on ...`the log message (5$) followed with the throwable and its backtrace (6$)`  Thanks SimpleFormatter docs! [Could have given me help but SimpleFormatter you have given me so much more!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cM8ir5NBsc0)

Comment: I... just don't agree. When I read the documentation, nothing about the list numbers makes me think it's related to `%[argument_index$]`, and I think the problem here is you thinking otherwise. Even if the list were zero-based, I still wouldn't interpret the list numbers as representing `%[argument_index$]`. That information comes from knowing the order of arguments to `String.format` and understanding how `java.util.Formatter` works.